# Making a predicate from a list

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

I want to make a predicate from this list.
 I have a list [apple,orange]. 
I try to make this predicate--->

fruits(apple,orange).

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a list into a term whose functor is the head of the list using `=..` (also called Univ). For example:

```
?- a(b) =.. [a, b].
true.
```

You can turn a term into a fact in the Prolog database using `assert/1`.

The solution to your question is thus:

```
?- List = [apple, orange], Term =.. [fruits | List], assert(Term).
List = [apple, orange],
Term = fruits(apple, orange).
```

You can now query your new fact to verify that it's there:

```
?- fruits(X, Y).
X = apple,
Y = orange.
```

Comment: @selda OK, I've added some explanation. This is very basic stuff, you'll find a better explanation in every Prolog book.